# How to send Data to ElasticSearch using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am new to Nodejs , I am working on chat application using nodejs and socket.io , i need to send customer chat message to  Elasticsearch using nodejs.

I have connected elasticsearch to using below code,

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'trace',
  connectionClass:'http' 
});

client.ping({
  // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout 
  requestTimeout: Infinity,

  // undocumented params are appended to the query string 
  hello: "elasticsearch!"
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
  }
});
```

I dont know where to set configuration, send customer message to elasticsearch. Suggest me how to do this?

Comment: I believe this post would help you https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/11/24/simple-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-node-js/

Comment: there's also I nice walkthrough here: https://www.compose.com/articles/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-and-node/